# Reporting out of Google Cloud Spanner - Google Data Studio connectors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to connect spanner with google data studio. I don't see any connectors for the spanner. Is there any plan to introduce in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native connector for Spanner in Data Studio at the moment. However, you can use the [Spanner API](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/) to create your own [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started). That will let you use spanner data directly in Data Studio.